# Remove single quotation character from string c++

Tags: c++

I have looked at various methods ranging from string.erase/ ispunct etc. and I cant simply get it working for my code.

My code is as follows:

```
ifstream infilei("test.txt")

**Second part of code......**

while ( !infilei.eof() )
{
    string wordlist;
    infilei >> wordlist;
    inputlist.push_back(wordlist);
}
```

The text.txt contains commas, single quotation, double quotations etc. and I need to remove them.

Where `infilei >> wordlist;` is shown, I have tried to use a if statement to remove strings with '"' etc. but it still does not remove single or double quotation. Is there another way or can I set an string.erase for above a certain ascii range? And is the a way to also send string to lower case during push_back?

Thank you

Comment: Show us the "if statement" you tried.

Comment: I've tried this but still does not remove the signal or double quotations: 

while ( !infilei.eof() ) { string wordlist; while (infilei >> wordlist) { for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++) { if (wordlist[i] == '.' || wordlist[i] == ',' || wordlist[i] == ';' || wordlist[i] == ';' || wordlist[i] == '\"' || wordlist[i] == '\'') { wordlist.erase(i); } } inputlist.push_back(wordlist);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the if statement like so `if(str[i]=='\"' or str[i]=='\'')` and as for the lowercase this should do it:

```
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
```

Comment: I've tried this but still does not remove the signal or double quotations:

 while ( !infilei.eof() )
 {
  string wordlist;
  while (infilei >> wordlist)
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++)
   {
    if (wordlist[i] == '.' || wordlist[i] == ',' || wordlist[i] == ';' || wordlist[i] == ';' || wordlist[i] == '\"' || wordlist[i] == '\'')
    {
     wordlist.erase(i);
    }
   }
   inputlist.push_back(wordlist);

Comment: std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower); Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will clean every " , . ' from mesy_string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Chars to be removed
bool has_chars(char c){
  if(c=='\"' || c=='.' || c==',' || c=='\'')
    return true;
  else
    return false;  
}

int main () {
  string messy_string="dfffsg.nfgfg,nsfvfvbnf\"nsdfnsdf\'ssvbssvns\"hhhfh\"";

  cout<< messy_string<<endl;

  remove_if (messy_string.begin(), messy_string.end(), has_chars);

  cout<< messy_string<<endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

You should be able to modify it to your needs.